# Rewriting Image saves a corrupted file (Python)

Tags: python, image, python-requests, io

```
    for i, pokemon in enumerate(pokemon):
        pokeurl = f"https://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/bank/normal/{pokemon}.png"
        r = requests.get(pokeurl, stream=True)
        open('pokemon.png', 'wb').write(r.content)
        #do_stuff
```

Hi, I'm Kind of new to python. Here for the first time the function is called, the images are saved (6 times, the size of pokemon). But then the second time I'm calling the same function, it saves a corrupted image.

Comment: Can you give an example of the `pokemon` list ?

Comment: pokemon = ["glaceon","aerodactyl","charizard","blastoise","greninja","haxorus","flareon","pikachu"]

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine its down to how you open the file.

As written in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

> Calling f.write() without using the with keyword or calling f.close() might result in the arguments of f.write() not being completely written to the disk, even if the program exits successfully.

So just use a context manager

```
with open('pokemon.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Note: you're also just overwriting the same`pokemon.png` so the loop is a bit unnecessary..

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it's still not working. Apparently, if I change my link to an Imgur link, it'll work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine after using an unique name to save the images locally:

```
import requests
import os

pokemons = [
    "glaceon", "aerodactyl", "charizard", "blastoise", "greninja", "haxorus",
    "flareon", "pikachu"
]

for i, pokemon in enumerate(pokemons):
    pokeurl = f"https://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/bank/normal/{pokemon}.png"
    r = requests.get(pokeurl, stream=True)
    open(f'/tmp/p/{pokemon}.png', 'wb').write(r.content)

# verify images saved
print(os.listdir('/tmp/p'))
```

Out:

```
['charizard.png', 'flareon.png', 'pikachu.png', 'haxorus.png', 'blastoise.png', 'aerodactyl.png', 'greninja.png', 'glaceon.png']
```

Comment: The individual files do exist, but they are corrupted? Can't open them, and are ~100 bytes

But since my code logic is that it won't have more than 6 pokemon, I just made a function that does the same thing and called it six times and it miraculously worked. It's something among the lines that the request can't get a downloadable resource in second try

Comment: All files I downloaded are fine (> 2KB) and accessible.